# Finding percentage of file directory

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to find the percentage of a file, and how much of a percentage it is taking in the file directory. Here is my code so far:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 if [ -f "$#" ]; then
    dname2=$(dirname "$1");
    dname=$(stat -c%s "$dname2");
    size=$(stat -c%s "$1");
    percent=$(($size % $dname));
echo $size;
echo $dname;
echo "File:" "$1" "(" $size "," $percent"% of " 
$dname2")";
fi;
```

As far as I'm concerned, the percent variable should be outputting how much percentage the file is taking, but instead it looks like it is only outputting the size variable. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are issues that you need to address

1. Script is using '%' to calculate percentage. This will give use the remainder. Use '/' to do divide.
2. Potential issue: Script is using 'stat' to calculate size of folder. Are you sure you do not need to calculate the size of ALL files in the folder ?

Those two can be addressed with:

```
dname2=$(dirname "$1");
# this will extract size in bytes of all files in the folder. See man du
dsize=$(du -b "$dname2" | awk '{ print $1 }');
size=$(stat -c%s "$1");
# Use 'du' to calculate size for folder and/or file, if needed
# size=$(du -b "$1" | awk '{ print $1 }');
percent=$((size*100/dsize));
...
echo $percent
```

Likewise, changing the 'size=' to use 'du' will allow the script to calculate the percentage of space used by a folder within a folder

Answer (score 0):

Change your percent to the line below

```
percent="$(echo "$size/$dname*100" | bc -l | colrm 5)";
```

Use colrm to control the decimal points